# Regular Expression to Detect Corporation name

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to detect and extract a company name (a substring) given a larger string. For example, the following could be formats for company names:

- Uber, Inc
- Uber Technologies, Inc.
- Google LLC
- Fiserv Corporation
- Fiserv Corp.

Assuming the string would include various other non relevant words, I need to extract the matching company name from the string. Example below:

```
"John works at Uber Technologies, Inc as a senior software engineer while Amanda works at Google LLC as a product manager"
```

The current regular expression I have so far is as follows: `(/(, ?)?(LLC|Inc|Co)\.?/` but it does not cover all these scenarios (and only detects the company name. Another use case for this would be in a copyright - where there's something like:

`"© 2019 Uber Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved"`. I would need to once again extract the company name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How would you expect your script/pattern to tell that the company name is `Uber Technologies, Inc` and not `Technologies, Inc` or `at Uber Technologies, Inc`?

Comment: I guess you could write something like `(?:[A-Z][a-z]*[ ]?)*,?[ ](?:LLC|Inc|Corporation|Corp|Co)` (see it here: https://regex101.com/r/dEwMW1/1) but that can still match false-positives. You need to come up with a solid rule. This one assumes that the words in the company name start with a capital letter and that the word before the company name (if any) does not.

Comment: What you are looking for is called Named Entity Recognition. This can't be done with with a regular expression, you need to use some good AI tools to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'd be pretty complicated, and you might want to design an expression maybe based on some preliminary data for those companies, which would still fail in some cases:

```
((?:[A-Z0-9]\S+\s+){1,5})(?:\s*,\s*)?(LLC|LC|L\.L\.C\.|L\.C\.|INC|Inc\.?|Co\.?|CO\.?)
```

If you'd have LLP/LP, Corp, Corp., Corporation and similar postfixes, you can add them to:

```
(LLC|LC|L\.L\.C\.|L\.C\.|INC|Inc\.?|Co\.?|CO\.?)
```

and there are edge cases, for instance, some companies names start with digits, if you might have them in your data.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/q86oAU/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/q86oAU/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---